# Count of items in Sharepoint list including all folders and subfolders using xslt code

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I am using the below line to store the count of list items whose status is not started in a XSLT variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="NotStarted" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(@Status='Not Started')])" />
```

but this returns only the items from the root folder and it doesn't check for the item within the folders or subfolders.

I have multiple folders and subfolders in the list.

Comment: Can you include code?

Comment: Please include xslt and xml to help with these sorts of questions.

Comment: Hi Jamie/Nat,thanks for the reply..actually thats the only line of code that is required..i just need the count of the rows, filtered as per some other columns value....but the result should also contain rows which are inside the folders of root folder

Comment: Everyting is fine with your xsl. You need to configure the datasource to "Show all items without folders".